# Magento tries to Load module from wrong namespace/company

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8, module

I Loaded a model called fabric_news using this code,

```
Mage::getModel('fabric_news/news')->getCollection();
```

But magento tries to load module from wrong name space. So It throws errors Like

> Warning: include(Mage/Magentostudy/News/Model/News.php): failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory  in
>   /var/www/test/magento_custom/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

Kindly help me to overcome this issue.

Another one thing When I call `Mage::getModel('fabric_news/news')->getCollection();` function in `fabric_news` module it is working well. but in `fabric_tool` module, It is not.

> fabric_news config.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Module configuration
 *
 * @author Fabric
 */
-->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Fabric_News>
            <version>1.0.0.0.1</version>
        </Fabric_News>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <fabric_news>
                <class>Fabric_News_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>news_resource</resourceModel>
            </fabric_news>
            <news_resource>
                <class>Fabric_News_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <news>
                        <table>fabric_news</table>
                    </news>
                </entities>
            </news_resource>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <fabric_news>
                <class>Fabric_News_Helper</class>
            </fabric_news>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <fabric_news>
                <class>Fabric_News_Block</class>
            </fabric_news>
        </blocks>
        <resources>
            <fabric_news_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Fabric_News</module>
                    <class>Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </fabric_news_setup>
        </resources>
        <events>
            <before_news_item_display>
                <observers>
                    <fabric_news>
                        <class>fabric_news/observer</class>
                        <method>beforeNewsDisplayed</method>
                    </fabric_news>
                </observers>
            </before_news_item_display>
        </events>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <fabric_news>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Fabric_News</module>
                    <frontName>news</frontName>
                </args>
            </fabric_news>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <fabric_news>
                    <file>fabric_news.xml</file>
                </fabric_news>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Fabric_News before="Mage_Adminhtml">Fabric_News_Adminhtml</Fabric_News>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <fabric_news>
                    <file>fabric_news.xml</file>
                </fabric_news>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
    <default>
        <news>
            <view>
                <enabled>1</enabled>
                <items_per_page>20</items_per_page>
                <days_difference>3</days_difference>
            </view>
        </news>
    </default>
</config>
```

Comment: What s the wrong module name?

Comment: magento loads correct module.. but It does not load correct name space.

Comment: What does your config.xml look like. Magento attempts to prefix a name space with `mage_` if if can't find the class name.

Comment: Paste your config.xml here.

Comment: Have updated my question

Comment: Hmm... There still seems to be some information that we are missing here. Your model is in the `fabric_news` namespace, but the error message shows Magento is failing to find the `magentostudy_news` namespace. Is there another module involved somehow?

Comment: That makes me confused.. I don't know why it comes. Mage::getModel('fabric_news/news')->getCollection() function works, When I call it in fabric_news module. But It does not, When I call it in fabric_tool @Cags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perform a case insensitive search of your entire module for the string `magentostudy`. Best guess is that in `app/code/{codePool}/Fabric/News/Resource/News.php` you'll have something like:

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('magentostudy_news/news', 'entity_id');
}
```

Comment: No, It has correct code like $this->_init('fabric_news/news','news_id');

Comment: ...and did you search for the string `magentostudy` in your entire project?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for trying to help me. The problem was with my editor. I searched so many times, But found no result. After you said, I changed my editor and searched magentostudy. And found and fixed. Now It is working well. @Cags