# Magento local version doesn't load extensions properly

Tags: magento-1.7, blocks, exception, third-party-module

I have a running live instance of Magento 1.7. I am trying to setup a local dev env.
Below is what I've done so far:

- Copy the project from server
- Import a dump of the database
- Edit local.xml with proper DB credentials
- Update core_config_data with new urls
- Run magento_cleanup (which properly sets rules, clean cache)

After those steps, the website is running but some pages are not properly rendered.

When I check the logs, it comes that pages with modules aren't rendered correctly. I have some "Invalid blocks" exceptions. Magento is looking for the blocks with "Mage" namespaces while the blocks are custom and have other namespaces.

Similar issues:

[custom model magento looks in Mage/...?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128376/custom-model-magento-looks-in-mage)

- Already done for my modules

[Magento tries to Load module from wrong namespace/company](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/59739/magento-tries-to-load-module-from-wrong-namespace-company)

- I am quite sure it isn't a case sensitivity issue.. My server is running PHP 5.6.17 while I am running PHP 5.6.40. Could it matter ?

My modules are listed on the backend however.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could be a filename case issue.  For example, confirm that if you have a class like the following: Vendor_Extension_Block_Test is saved as Test.php with capital T.  If lowercase t you will see block not found.  Same with controllers eg IndexController.php etc

Comment: Oops.  You edited question as I was replying.

Comment: My bad, sorry..
I have checked it again and it's fine with the file names and the classes on modules config.